# SQL Query via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been working on an SQL project. I have a table with two columns, and a search feature in which the user is asked to enter the username in a simple form. Then my php script echoes the Full Name associated with that username.

Here is the HTML page containing the form:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
       <title>Search  Contacts</title> 
    </head> 
<p><body> 
    <h3>Search  Contacts Details</h3> 
    <p>You  may search either by first or last name</p> 
        <form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform"> 
            <input  type="text" name="username"> 
            <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
        </form> 
</body>
```

Here is the php script that echoes the full name:

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","hidden","users");

   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   $username=['username']
   $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` LIKE $username";
   if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
      // Get field information for all fields
      while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result))
      {
          $username =$fieldinfo ['username'];
      }

      // Free result set
      echo $username;
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I wish you good luck with your work! If you have any problems, feel free to ask :)

Comment: @MartinHeralecký i have a problem in my php script it says server error, but i am 15 years old and i cannot solve it.

Comment: Strings need to be in quotes in SQL. But it would be better if you learned to use prepared queries, instead of substituting into the SQL.

Comment: `$username=['username']` should be `$username=$_POST['username'];`

Comment: you are missing a semi-colon after `$username=['username']` and it's not valid - like @Dagon said - `$_POST['username'];`

Comment: @Barmar colud you give me some examples of prepared queries, or maybe you can fix some line in my code?

Comment: And `echo $username;` should probably be inside the `while` cycle, if you want to echo all possible results, not just the last one.

Comment: this is full of syntax errors

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, i managed to fix my problem and now my system is working.

Answer (score 2):

The username is a string, so it needs to be in quotes.

You're also missing a semicolon on the line that assigns to `$username`, and the value you're assigning should be `$_POST['username']`.

And if the query fails, you should display the error message containing the reason for the failure.

You're only echoing the last username matched. You should move the `echo` statement inside the loop.

To make `LIKE` search for any user whose name contains `$username`, you need to put the wildcard `%` characters around the search string used with `LIKE`.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","hidden","users");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$username=$_POST['username'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` LIKE '%$username%'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        // Get field information for all fields
        while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result))
            {
                $username =$fieldinfo ['username'];
                echo $username;
            }
    }
else 
    {
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But it would be better if you learned to use prepared queries. Here's your code rewritten in this style.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","hidden","users");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$username=$_POST['username'];
$sql="SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE `user` LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysql_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
if ($result=mysqli_execute($stmt))
    {
        mysqli_bind_result($stmt, $username);
        // Get field information for all fields
        while (mysql_fetch($stmt)) {
            echo $username;
        }
    }
else
    {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: should that not be `$username='%'.$_POST['username'].'%';` to account for the wildcard aspect of a `like` search?

Comment: like is valid with out wildcards, but is still different than =. Not that i suspect the OP knows this :-)

Comment: @Dagon I think you mean it's **not** different from `=`.

Comment: no **is** different "*Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:*" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html